# CheckBoxFor en Razor con valor bit MySQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Podrían ayudarme por favor. Tengo en mi base de datos `MySQL` campos Bit(1), hago el `Model` y lo trabajo en el controlador con `true` o `false` (`Boolean`), hasta ahí todo bien. En `Razor` llamo a mi campo así:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Almacenamiento.Value)
```

En mi tabla `MySQL` los valores están por defecto en 0, en la vista sí muestra correctamente el `CheckBox` de acuerdo al valor de `MySQL`, si en `MySQL` está en 0 el `CheckBox` aparece desmarcado, si está en 1 el `CheckBox` aparece marcado, hasta ahí todo me anda bien.

Mi problema es al guardar o editar, ya que cuando me muestra la vista y quiero marcar o desmarcar un `CheckBox` para que en la base de datos me actualice, en el controlador cuando llega el objeto y miro ese campo, ese campo llega como `null`. No sé si me dejo entender. ¿Alguna ayuda? Lo que quiero es que al editar y guardar, en el controlador llegue su campo como `true` o `false` pero solo llega como `null`.

asi es como esta las propiedades de la clase en mi data model:

```
    public Nullable<bool> IngresoSite { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IngresoNodoInterconexion { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Almacenamiento { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> PruebaConectividad { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IngresoFibraGabinete { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IngresoEquipoTX { get; set; }
```

son varios.
 y asi es como lo recibo en el controlador:

> [Authorize]   [HttpPost]
>       public ActionResult DiagramaTransmision(Transmision objTrans) { aqui solo recibo el objeto y comienzo a operar, pero en la propiedad
>   que mencione solo aparece null. return View(); }

---

asi es como esta las propiedades de la clase en mi data model:

```
    public Nullable<bool> IngresoSite { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IngresoNodoInterconexion { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Almacenamiento { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> PruebaConectividad { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IngresoFibraGabinete { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IngresoEquipoTX { get; set; }
```

son varios.
 y asi es como lo recibo en el controlador:

> [Authorize]   [HttpPost]
>       public ActionResult DiagramaTransmision(Transmision objTrans) { aqui solo recibo el objeto y comienzo a operar, pero en la propiedad
>   que mencione solo aparece null. return View(); }

Comment: de casualidad sucede lo mismo cuando: 1) marcas y envías la actualización. 2) desmarcas y envías la actualización ?

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el código de la edición o el guardado para ver cómo se maneja el modelo?

Comment: que tipo de dato asignas a ese campos, porque si es bool no puede recibir nunca un null, salvo que sea un bool?

Comment: sucede lo mismo al descarmar y marcar y guaradandolo, en controlador recibe el objeto con esas propiedades en null, cosa que me parece raro ya que cuando envio el tipo deobjeto a razor model, los valores se envian con true y false, solo en el guardar me esta seteando a null todo.

Answer (score 1):

Yo cambiaría

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Almacenamiento.Value)
```

Por

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Almacenamiento)
```

Comment: esto es lo mismo que un checkbox????

Comment: En el caso del `EditorFor` el mismo compilador traduce el tipo de dato y lo convierte a un control, por ejemplo, si es un `string` lo traduce a un `TextBox`, un `int` lo traduce a un `Spinner` numérico, y un `bool` lo traduce a un `CheckBox`

Comment: si, esta genial, me devuelve un checkbox, pero igual al descarmarcarlo o marcarlo y guardandolo, el controlador recibe el objeto pero con esas propiedades en null, pero al momento de enviar el objeto al la view para que renderize la data, en el depurador se puede mirar los true y false.

Comment: Una pregunta amigo, ¿lo dejas como `model.Almacenamiento.Value` o como `model.Almacenamiento`? Sugiero que en el modelo lo declares solo como `public bool Almacenamiento { get; set; }` y realices una prueba

Comment: Lo pongo con .value porque si no le pongo le salta error. La clase se genera sola con entity data model.

Comment: Bien, el `.Value` es necesario porque estás dejando la variable declarada como `Nullable<bool>`, simplemente declárala como `bool` y quítale el `.Value`, hagamos esa prueba para ver qué comportamiento tiene

Comment: Tenias razon amigo, ese nullable era el que molestaba, le puse solo bool y ahora si llega la data normal. gracias por tu gran ayudaaa.